# convert error from const string to const uint8_t*

Tags: c++

I'm try to writing a program to compress a text with lzma. I copied an example from Github and I'm trying to rewrite it bit by bit for my request. But unfortunately it doesn't quite work.  Because with the main function I get the error:

```
lzma.cpp: In function ‘void testIt(const char*, int)’:
lzma.cpp:107:46: error: cannot convert ‘const string’ {aka ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’} to ‘const uint8_t*’ {aka ‘const unsigned char*’}
  auto compressedBlob = lzmaCompress(b64encode(input, size), size, &compressedSize);
                                     ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
lzma.cpp:29:56: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘std::unique_ptr<unsigned char []> lzmaCompress(const uint8_t*, uint32_t, uint32_t*)’
 std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> lzmaCompress(const uint8_t *input, uint32_t inputSize, uint32_t *outputSize) {
```

Unfortunately I have no idea what the error could be. I have tried a lot of things, but nothing worked. Maybe you can help me. Maybe you can find something else that could be improved :)

lzma.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <memory>
#include "base64.hpp"
extern "C" {
#include "lzma/LzmaEnc.h"
#include "lzma/LzmaDec.h"
}



static void *_lzmaAlloc(ISzAllocPtr, size_t size) {
    return new uint8_t[size];
}
static void _lzmaFree(ISzAllocPtr, void *addr) {
    if (!addr)
        return;

    delete[] reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(addr);
}

static ISzAlloc _allocFuncs = {
    _lzmaAlloc, _lzmaFree
};



std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> lzmaCompress(const uint8_t *input, uint32_t inputSize, uint32_t *outputSize) {
    std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> result;

    // set up properties
    CLzmaEncProps props;
    LzmaEncProps_Init(&props);
    if (inputSize >= (1 << 20))
        props.dictSize = 1 << 20; // 1mb dictionary
    else
        props.dictSize = inputSize; // smaller dictionary = faster!
    props.fb = 40;

    // prepare space for the encoded properties
    SizeT propsSize = 5;
    uint8_t propsEncoded[5];

    // allocate some space for the compression output
    // this is way more than necessary in most cases...
    // but better safe than sorry
    //   (a smarter implementation would use a growing buffer,
    //    but this requires a bunch of fuckery that is out of
    ///   scope for this simple example)
    SizeT outputSize64 = inputSize * 1.5;
    if (outputSize64 < 1024)
        outputSize64 = 1024;
    auto output = std::make_unique<uint8_t[]>(outputSize64);

    int lzmaStatus = LzmaEncode(
        output.get(), &outputSize64, input, inputSize,
        &props, propsEncoded, &propsSize, 0,
        NULL,
        &_allocFuncs, &_allocFuncs);

    *outputSize = outputSize64 + 13;
    if (lzmaStatus == SZ_OK) {
        // tricky: we have to generate the LZMA header
        // 5 bytes properties + 8 byte uncompressed size
        result = std::make_unique<uint8_t[]>(outputSize64 + 13);
        uint8_t *resultData = result.get();

        memcpy(resultData, propsEncoded, 5);
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            resultData[5 + i] = (inputSize >> (i * 8)) & 0xFF;
        memcpy(resultData + 13, output.get(), outputSize64);
    }

    return result;
}


std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> lzmaDecompress(const uint8_t *input, uint32_t inputSize, uint32_t *outputSize) {
    if (inputSize < 13)
        return NULL; // invalid header!

    // extract the size from the header
    UInt64 size = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        size |= (input[5 + i] << (i * 8));

    if (size <= (256 * 1024 * 1024)) {
        auto blob = std::make_unique<uint8_t[]>(size);

        ELzmaStatus lzmaStatus;
        SizeT procOutSize = size, procInSize = inputSize - 13;
        int status = LzmaDecode(blob.get(), &procOutSize, &input[13], &procInSize, input, 5, LZMA_FINISH_END, &lzmaStatus, &_allocFuncs);

        if (status == SZ_OK && procOutSize == size) {
            *outputSize = size;
            return blob;
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}


void testIt(const char*input, int size) { //uint8_t
    uint32_t compressedSize;
    auto compressedBlob = lzmaCompress(b64encode(input, size), size, &compressedSize);
    uint32_t decompressedSize;
    printf("%u\n", (unsigned int)decompressedSize);
    printf("%u\n", (unsigned int)compressedSize);
    auto decompressedBlob = lzmaDecompress(compressedBlob.get(), compressedSize, &decompressedSize);
    const char* decoded_tar = b64decode(decompressedBlob.get(), compressedSize).c_str();
    printf(decoded_tar);
    printf("----------\n");
}

void testIt(const char *string) {
    testIt(string, strlen(string)); //(const uint8_t *)
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    testIt("a");
    testIt("here is a cool string");
    testIt("here's something that should compress pretty well: abcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdef");

    return 0;
}
```

base64.hpp

```
#include <string>

static const char* B64chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

static const int B64index[256] =
{
    0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
    0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
    0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  62, 63, 62, 62, 63,
    52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
    0,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
    15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 0,  0,  0,  0,  63,
    0,  26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40,
    41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51
};

const std::string b64encode(const void* data, const size_t &len)
{
    std::string result((len + 2) / 3 * 4, '=');
    char *p = (char*) data, *str = &result[0];
    size_t j = 0, pad = len % 3;
    const size_t last = len - pad;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < last; i += 3)
    {
        int n = int(p[i]) << 16 | int(p[i + 1]) << 8 | p[i + 2];
        str[j++] = B64chars[n >> 18];
        str[j++] = B64chars[n >> 12 & 0x3F];
        str[j++] = B64chars[n >> 6 & 0x3F];
        str[j++] = B64chars[n & 0x3F];
    }
    if (pad)  /// set padding
    {
        int n = --pad ? int(p[last]) << 8 | p[last + 1] : p[last];
        str[j++] = B64chars[pad ? n >> 10 & 0x3F : n >> 2];
        str[j++] = B64chars[pad ? n >> 4 & 0x03F : n << 4 & 0x3F];
        str[j++] = pad ? B64chars[n << 2 & 0x3F] : '=';
    }
    return result;
}

const std::string b64decode(const void* data, const size_t &len)
{
    if (len == 0) return "";

    unsigned char *p = (unsigned char*) data;
    size_t j = 0,
        pad1 = len % 4 || p[len - 1] == '=',
        pad2 = pad1 && (len % 4 > 2 || p[len - 2] != '=');
    const size_t last = (len - pad1) / 4 << 2;
    std::string result(last / 4 * 3 + pad1 + pad2, '\0');
    unsigned char *str = (unsigned char*) &result[0];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < last; i += 4)
    {
        int n = B64index[p[i]] << 18 | B64index[p[i + 1]] << 12 | B64index[p[i + 2]] << 6 | B64index[p[i + 3]];
        str[j++] = n >> 16;
        str[j++] = n >> 8 & 0xFF;
        str[j++] = n & 0xFF;
    }
    if (pad1)
    {
        int n = B64index[p[last]] << 18 | B64index[p[last + 1]] << 12;
        str[j++] = n >> 16;
        if (pad2)
        {
            n |= B64index[p[last + 2]] << 6;
            str[j++] = n >> 8 & 0xFF;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
//std::string
std::string b64encode(const std::string& str)
{
    return b64encode(str.c_str(), str.size());
}

std::string b64decode(const std::string& str64)
{
    return b64decode(str64.c_str(), str64.size());
}
```

Comment: "Unfortunately I have no idea what the error could be" - Why not? It tells you clearly. `b64decode()` returns an `std::string`, but you try to pass that as the 1st argument of `lzmaCompress()`, which expect a pointer to (an array of) `const std::uint8_t`. Those are not the same thing, as the compiler already clearly explained. So you need to find a way to convert between them. Thankfully, that should be easy and well-documented.

Comment: You can probably simply store the result of `b64decode()` in a local `std::string` and pass its `.data()` to `lzmaCompress()`, since `.data()` returns a `char*` or `const char*`, and in practice an `std::uint8_t` is going to be a `char` type of some kind, although you might still need to `reinterpret_cast` a little to get to the `const unsigned char*` that `const std::uint8_t*` likely is.

Comment: @underscore_d If you write this as an answer I accept it.

Comment: @BIOS Thanks! I have done so. Let me know if you want to request any edits to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the error is telling us is that `b64decode()` returns an `std::string`, but you try to pass that as the 1st argument of `lzmaCompress()`, which expects a pointer to (an array of) `const std::uint8_t`. Those are not the same thing. Since this is C++ and we can define implicit conversions in several ways, inexact matches for declared argument types aren't an error, the compiler helpfully tries to convert them for us - but no conversion is declared, so it can't, hence the specific error you get.

You can probably simply store the result of `b64decode()` in a local `std::string` and pass its `.data()` to `lzmaCompress()`, since `.data()` can return a `const char*`, and in practice (if not necessarily in theory) an `std::uint8_t` is going to be an `unsigned char`. You will still need to `reinterpret_cast` to get to the `const std::uint8_t*`, since `.data()` returns a `[const] char*`, i.e. not yet an unsigned character.

Try this, or something very like it (I can't test it):

```cpp
auto const b64encoded = b64encode(input, size);
auto const b64encoded_data_u8 = reinterpret_cast<const std::uint8_t*>( b64encoded.data() );
auto const compressedBlob = lzmaCompress(b64encoded_data_u8, size, &compressedSize);
```

Of course, ensure the `b64encoded` string outlives anyone reading its `.data()` in-place

Answer (score 0):

`b64encode` returns a std::string, while the first argument of `lzmaCompress` is expected to be of type uint8_t*. You'll need to convert the string output to uint8_t* before calling the `lzmaCompress` function.

Comment: and how might they do that? since you just paraphrased my 1st comment, why not go ahead and do the 2nd...

Comment: @underscore_d good point. But you could really get the credit if you write an answer yourself ;)